# Is there a group with finitely many generators of order 2 that is not a Coxeter group?

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

Maybe I am missing something obvious here. But in [this](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/Coxeter/lectures.html) series of lectures the following is proved to be equivalent **under the assumption** that the group $W$ has a (finite) set of generators $S$ whose elements are all of order 2:

- $(W,S)$ is a Coxeter system
- $(W,S)$ has the exchange property
- $(W,S)$ has the deletion property

I am puzzled why the assumption is necessary because it seems to imply that there is a group $W$ generated by the elements of a set $S$ with $s\in S\implies s^2=e$ which is not a Coxeter group. But is that property not enough to conclude that $W$ **is** a Coxeter group? In other words, can there be anything else than the relations $(s_{i}s_{j})^n=e$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup \{ \infty \}$?

**Edit:**
I should have waited for the next (the seventh) video where it was (AFAICT) mentioned for the first time, that a Coxeter group can have **only** such relations that are consequences of the given orders of the product of all the pairs of generators. I can see now that my question looks a bit silly.

Comment: What about $\langle a,b,c\mid a^2,b^2,c^2,(abc)^2\rangle$?

Comment: Of course there could be relations other than $(s_is_j)^2$ - whyever not? Every finite nonabelian simple group is generated by three elements of order $2$, and none of those are Coxeter groups, because they don't have subgroups of index $2$.

Comment: @SteveD But that doesn't necessarily mean that that group isn't Coexeter, right? $ab$, $ac$ and $bc$ will have some allowed order. Or does the fact that $abc$ has order 3 violate that somehow?

Comment: Try proving that every Coxeter group maps surjectively to the group of order 2. So *any* group generated by order-2 elements which doesn't have that map answers your question, right?

Comment: @DerekHolt I didn't say, that there can't ben any other relations, I explicitly said that the exponent can be any integer or $\infty$ for $i\neq j$. Can you give a small example of such a group? And I don't see any mentioning of the group having to have a subgroup of index 2 in the definition (although it should follow from the fact that half of the elements have even and the other half odd length.)

Comment: @SteveD I know what you mean. What I don't understand is how your group should violate the definition of a Coxeter group. Wikipedia and the lecture I was referring to only say something about relations of the form $(s_{i}s_{j})^n$ but nothing about relations involving more than 2 generators.

Comment: A coxeter group is defined by *only* those relators you've seen involving the $s_is_j$. Explicitly, every relation that holds in a coxeter group can be derived from the $s_is_j$ relations. So if you have a group that has an extra relation, that is not derivable from these $s_is_j$ relations, it cannot be a Coxeter group. That is the point of my and Derek's examples.

Comment: The smallest nonabelian simple group is $A_5$ of order $60$.